# Changed value in ViewController gets reset after returning from segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My app has two ViewControllers that I switch back and forth through segues.  The first (main) VC has a number of variables that are initialized.  The second VC is a keypad editor which can change one of the variables in the first VC; the first VC sends an indicator as to which variable to change, and the second VC sends back the new value.

However, if I change a value, then change a second value, the first value that was changed resets to its initial value.

Here is the first ViewController (at least, the parts needed for the example):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var idToChange: Int;
    var ValueOne: Int;
    var ValueTwo: Int;

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        idToChange = 0;
        ValueOne = 1;
        ValueTwo = 2;
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }

    @IBAction func clickChangeValue1(B: UIButton)
    {
        idToChange = 1;
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segueKeypadView", sender: self);
    }

    @IBAction func clickChangeValue2(B: UIButton)
    {
        idToChange = 2;
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segueKeypadView", sender: self);
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var vc: KeypadViewController = segue.destinationViewController as KeypadViewController;
        vc.idToChange = idToChange;
    }
}
```

and here is the second ViewController:

```
class KeypadViewController: UIViewController {

    var idToChange: Int;
    var changedValue: Int;

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        idToChange = 0;
        changedValue = 0;
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }
    // Note that idToChange is set correctly by the segue

    // Code that sets changedValue left out

    @IBAction func clickTheOKButton(B: UIButton)
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("segueMainView", sender: self);
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var vc: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController;
        switch (idToChange)
        {
            case 1:
                vc.ValueOne = changedValue;
            case 2:
                vc.ValueTwo = changedValue;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the main controller requests that Value1 be changed, and the second controller tries to change Value1 to 10, then Value1 is 10.
However, if the main controller then requests that Value2 be changed, and the second controller tries to change Value2 to 20, then Value2 becomes 20, but Value1 is set back to its initialized value of 1.

Short of passing all of the changeable values in the first controller to the second one, and then having the second one send them all back (after any changes) to the first one, is there any way to have the second controller change one value without the other ones being reset?

Comment: Are you using an unwind segue to go back to the first controller? If not, then you're not actually going back, you're instantiating a new controller.

Comment: "Un - wind - seg - ue?"  Your ideas intrigue me and I wish to subscribe to your newsletter.  (Seriously, that solved it - thanks.)

Answer (score 2):

When you trigger a Segue it initialises a new ViewController. You should use "back button" or `popViewController`

Like this:

```
class KeypadViewController: UIViewController {

  var idToChange: Int;
    var changedValue: Int;

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        idToChange = 0;
        changedValue = 0;
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }
    // Note that idToChange is set correctly by the segue

    // Code that sets changedValue left out

    @IBAction func clickTheOKButton(B: UIButton) {
        var vc: ViewController = self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] as ViewController // Your view controller's index.
        switch (idToChange) {
            case 1:
                vc.ValueOne = changedValue;
                break;
            case 2:
                vc.ValueTwo = changedValue;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered by rdelmar in his comment to my original question.  (This was added as I couldn't find a way to mark a comment to the original question as an answer.)